# Different output in terminal in Ubuntu 14 and Ubuntu 16

Tags: java, replace, ubuntu-14.04, locale

I hope you can help me with my problem:

**CONTEXT**

I'm working on a Java application. Following java, instruction works properly in in Ubuntu 16, but It fails when deploying on an Ubuntu 14.

```
String test = "Für test with and without Ü".replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]+", ",");
System.out.println(test);
```

**PROBLEM**

**German characters are not properly shown** on ubuntu 14.04. In Ubuntu 16 works perfectly, like you can see in the images

**Output in Ubuntu 16**

[image]

**Output in Ubuntu 14.04**

[image]

I have to try to set locales in Ubuntu 14 but I don't really know what is the problem

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe the locale is missing in Ubuntu 14.04, did you try adding it manually in 14.04?

Comment: Looks like your machine doesn't have UTF8 support. Try changing the language pack or downloading a UTF-8 fontpack

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add the locale manually in Ubuntu 14.04. Try the following:

METHOD 1:

`locale -a`

This will list the supported locales.

`sudo locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8`

This will install the locale on your machine.

`sudo update-locale`

This will effect the changes.

METHOD 2:

You can also try downloading the required package by:

`sudo apt-get install language-pack-DE`

This should fix your problem of locales.

Comment: Thanks! it works. The problem was actually a combination of two problems: the "locale" configuration and the way I was writing the content (was not UTF-8 by default)